# Relationship between Two Tables with Constraints

Tags: mysql-workbench

I have two tables with Primary Keys as Constraints. I want to create a EER Diagram with that correct relationship. I suggest that this relationship is as 1:N relationship, am I correct? Now if I make this relationship in  Mysqlworkbench the tool creates automatic forging key on the one table, but I don't want that if I delete the forging key the relationship arrow disappears how to make visualatio this relation in MySQL workbench? Also my goal is to put both tables into one table. And I don't know if I do it correct. Can someone explain to me the relationship?

1.

```
CREATE TABLE `station`(
    `track_id` VARCHAR(64) 
    `station_id` VARCHAR(30) 
    `module` TINYINT(3) 
    PRIMARY KEY (`track_id`, `station_id`) USING BTREE
)
```

2. 

```
CREATE TABLE `positions` (
    `track_id` VARCHAR(64)
    `station_id` VARCHAR(30) 
    `position_id` VARCHAR(6) 
    `station` TINYINT(3) 
    PRIMARY KEY (`track_id`, `station_id`, `position_id`) USING BTREE
)
```

My idea of the third table. Is my suggestion correct?

3.

```
CREATE TABLE `station_positions` (
    `track_id` VARCHAR(64) 
    `station_id` VARCHAR(30) 
    `position_id` VARCHAR(6) 
    `module` TINYINT(3) 
    `station` TINYINT(3) 
    PRIMARY KEY (`track_id`, `station_id`,`position_id`) USING BTREE
)
```

Comment: sorry my fault.

Comment: We don't know what the data in your tables represent, how are we supposed to help you? I can try my best guess, but to be honest, I don't really have any ideas. Radio stations?

Comment: In the first table ist for track_i=1,station_id=1,module=xy, the second table have track_i=1,station_id=1,postion_id=1,station=xy,track_id=1,station_id=1,postion_id=2,station=xyz.

Comment: You're making this too "technical". Database design starts by knowing the domain you're trying to model. Are these train stations? Give us a clue. Model trains?

Comment: First table contains all assembly line stations configuration. Second table contains positions on assembly line.

Comment: OK, I don't know the first thing about assembly lines. No idea what the difference is between a station and a position, why a station has a module, or what the difference is between a "station", for which you have a table, and a "station" that's a field in the positions table. Sorry, I can't help you.

Comment: The module in the first  is the Identification of load data module used by station. The station in the secod table Indicate position launch type. Track_id is  PC name which drive assembly line. station_id The working station name. postion_id is the station position identification.

Comment: The relationship between the table 1 and 2 one to many. Can my third table show all information of these table . Is this technical ok ?

Comment: Thank you for that clarification. I still don't feel that I can help you with this. I was however wondering if you have heard of **database normalization**? Most discussion about this are quite abstract, but it is useful to know about it. It might dissuade you from trying to put everything in one table, especially if you already know there's a 1:N relation. A basic rule is to not have the same data in multiple position in a database. Perhaps check out [this bit in the MariaDB documentaion](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/database-normalization/) (MariaDB = MySQL).

Comment: Thank you for your fast answer. I know about normalization but with putting the table into one table i can speed up my queries with avoiding joins.

Comment: @KIKOSoftware mariadb is **not** mysql, it is a **fork** of mysql, with increased number of differences!

Comment: @Shadow: I only intended that as a hint that [MariaDB is a compatible drop-in replacement for the widely used MySQL](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/difference-between-mysql-and-mariadb/), implying that the documentation I pointed at would be relevant for a MySQL user.

Comment: @KIKOSoftware that article is wrong on many, many accounts! See mariadb's own assessment: https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb-vs-mysql-compatibility/ Key sentence: "Until MariaDB 5.5, MariaDB versions functioned as a "drop-in replacement" for the equivalent MySQL version, with some limitations. From MariaDB 10.0, it is usually still very easy to upgrade from MySQL."

Comment: @Shadow: This discussion is irrelevant. It was never my intention to claim that MariaDB **literally is** MySQL, it's only something you decided to take away from my comment. Ah, btw, I am happily using MariaDB as a replacement for MySQL.

Comment: @KIKOSoftware well, you literally wrote MariaDB = MySQL, which is hard to interpret in any other way! I have bumped into questions here on SO, where I spent hours figuring out what could have gone wrong, just to find out that the OP was using mariadb and not mysql! However, if the OP uses mysql, then reference mysql sources and not mariadb (same true for the other way around), just to make sure that the reference is correct for their database product!

Comment: @Shadow: It would be more relevant to discuss whether Woranhatgelegen's idea that a JOIN would slow down queries is a valid reason not to normalize a database. Perhaps another solution, that doesn't use a relational database, would be better.

Comment: @KIKOSoftware I also lack the domain knowledge, so it's a pass from me.